# How to serve angular with golang?

Tags: go

I am trying it using `http.FileServe` providing the directory of angular app. But instead I get the list of files in that folder. I am using gorilla mux package.

If it is for a simple `html` file it does work but not for angular app.

```
router := mux.NewRouter()
router.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/src/app")))
```

This lists all files in directory in `./static/src/app` when went to that url. How should I correctly do it ?

Comment: Have you actually built the angular app?

Comment: Does that folder contain index.html?

Comment: @Milan Velebit I do have a working app on localhost.

Comment: @Krishna Chaitanya Kornepati No it doesn't contain that file.

Comment: To serve angular app as first you need to build it, and then serve `dist` directory which will be created after building in your root project directory. So it probably will be `./static/dist`.

Comment: angular app needs to be build before it can be served by a simple file server and the folder needs to have index.html to show a webpage if you open it. which will be generated once you build it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Angular application is most likely served via its own NodeJS server (by default on port *4200* if I remember). You need to run `ng build` if you've created the app via *Angular cli*.

Afterwards, serve the `index.html` file inside the */dist* folder which'll be created upon running `ng build`. That file contains the minified, bundled JS which can be served via any webserver.

Comment: This `index.html` will have whatever I create in the `src/app` directory ? Also, I did as you said I am able to get the page served on the url.

Comment: @ameyCU Yes, you can read about it [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build)

Answer (score 0):

the "static" is the folder in root project, with your files angular built, this will router to folder "static" when you call "http://localhost:4200" or when not find a router.

```
  func server() {
   router := gin.Default()
   router.Static("/", "./static")
   router.NoRoute(func(c *gin.Context) {
      c.File("./static/index.html")
   })
   router.Run(":4200")
 }
```